# get the words between two specific characters in php

Tags: php, regex

How to get the words between the characters "--#" and "#--"
I tried regex and explode but I cant get the desired output.

**output must be :** *Section 2, Section 3, Section 4, Section 5*
.................................................................................

--#Section 2#--
-##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt##-

--#Section 3#--
-##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt##-

--#Section 4#--
-##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt##-

--#Section 5#--
-##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt##-

Comment: @fedorqui: or none - most likely

Comment: `/#(.*?)#/`, perhaps?

Comment: its actually php and regex only., i just clicked the suggestion., and sorry for that. by the way thanks to those who help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the title of the question clearly states:

> get the words between two specific characters in `php`....

You can use this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/--#(.*?)#--/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Explanation**:

```
--#      # match '--#'
(        # group and capture to \1:
  .*?    #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
)        # end of \1
#--      # match '#--'
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/173751)

Comment: this is what i need., thanks a lot, hope it can help to some people too.,

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*--#\(.*\)#--.*/\1/g' file
Section 2

Section 3

Section 4

Section 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
--#(.*)#--
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM8dX2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you use BASH

a simple answer without using sed or any other command is by doing the following

```
 VAR="--#Section 2#-- -##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt##-"

 #delete from the tail 
 VAR=${VAR%%'#--'*}                             //you will get VAR="--#Section 2"
 #delete from the head
 VAR=${VAR##*'--#'}                             //NOW you'll have VAR="Section 2"
```